# webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-dev-middleware

I don't have webpack-dev-middleware installed in my project but when I build it using webpack it throws below warning.

> webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed

Below are webpack related lib's I am using in my project.

> "webpack": "^4.15.0",
>       "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
>       "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
>       "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"

Any idea how to fix this warning.

Answer (score 3):

try deleting your `node_modules` directory and then install packages again `npm install`. It worked to me